# GitHub GraphQL equivalent of the contents API

Tags: github, github-api, graphql

Does GitHub's [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/explorer/) have an equivalent to the [contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents)?

I can't seem to come up with a query that accepts repo owner, repo name and file path and returns the contents of the file. I'm guessing it has something to do with the [tree](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/tree/) object?

https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/explorer/

Answer (score 67, accepted):

After some digging, found it:

```
query {
  repository(name: "repoName", owner: "repoOwner") {
    object(expression: "branch:path/to/file") {
      ... on Blob {
        text
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The argument passed to `expression` on the `object` field is actually a git revision expression suitable for `rev-parse`, so I guess you can have fun with it to do advanced querying.

Documentation:

- [Repository object on GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/repository/)
- [rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)

Comment: what about binary content with base64 encoded? we have that in v3, but couldn't find a way in v4.

Comment: what's the "..." supposed to be?

Comment: @SW_user2953243 GraphQL syntax, do not replace the dots

Comment: @SW_user2953243 You are querying for a `GitObject`, which could be a `Blob` (file), but could also be a `Commit`, `Tag` or `Tree`. The `... on Blob` is an [inline fragment](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments), that allows you to conditionally query for the `text` field if the returned `GitObject` is a `Blob`.

Comment: @SamTolmay I tried same with Tag GitObject but getting empty response. Have any ideas? For invalid tags getting null object. For valid tags only empty json object.
{
  repository(owner: "gradle", name: "gradle") {
    url
    object(expression: "v5.3.0") {
      ... on Tag {
        oid
        id
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Does not work when the object is a submodule: it returns `object: null`.