# How do I query the GitHub v4 API for directory contents at a certain tag?

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-graphql

How do I query the [GitHub API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/) for the contents of a certain directory of a repository at a certain tag?

This is the best I've come up with so far:

```
query {
  repository(owner:"example", name:"example") {
    refs(refPrefix: "tags") {
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137710/github-graphql-equivalent-of-the-contents-api), you can get the `GitObject` with `object` to filter on `branch:/path/folder` and print the `Tree`. The following will get the tree from `gson` folder from tag `gson-2.4` and print `name`, `type` and `mode` :

```
query {
  repository(owner:"google", name:"gson") {
      object(expression: "gson-2.4:gson") {
      ... on Tree{
        entries{
          name
          type
          mode
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Instead of `tag` used here, can I use `branch` as seen in your linked post? So I would do `expression: "master:gson"`