# github graphql api default branch in repository

Tags: api, github, graphql

I have the following query:

```
{
  repository(owner: "org", name: "name") {
    name
    object(expression: "master:package.json") {
      ... on Blob {
        text
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but as you can see I have to hardcode `master` in the object expression.  I'm wondering if there's a way to instead use the default branch in that query.  Is that possible without having to do 2 queries (1 to get the default branch, then another to get the file content)?

Answer (score 3):

There was a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44282072/6309) (with bounty too) on that, detailed [in this thread](https://platform.github.community/t/query-repo-contents-with-graphql-api/1896/6)... but it is the syntax you are using:

> The argument passed to expression on the [`object` field](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/repository/) is actually a git revision expression suitable for **[`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)**, so I guess you can have fun with it to do advanced querying.

So any way to [**specify a revision**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions) should do, including HEAD, which would reference the default remote branch. But not the "current branch" though.

Comment: ok but in that example they use `expression: "branch:path/to/file"` what I want to know is what do i use in place of 'branch' so that it uses the default branch?  'master' isn't always the default...

Comment: @Ben yes, master is not always the default branch, which is why I suggest in my answer to use HEAD: that should reference the default branch. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485590/6309